# Finding an element of a class inside a previous <li>

Tags: jquery

I have this code that should trigger mouseover and mouseout on a picture when I hover over it's comment, but it's not working as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.description").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).prev().find(".design").trigger('mouseout');
    });

    $("li.description").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).prev().find(".design").trigger('mouseover');
    });
});
```

This is part of the structure of the table:

```
<li>
    <img class="photography"  src="PHOTO/boat.jpg" alt="Boat on sea." />
</li>
<li>
    <div id="description" class="description">
        <p>BOAT</p>
        <p>ITALY</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

I have a bunch of images and descriptions in my table.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `<li>` with class "description", but your code only has `<div>`s with that class.

Additionally, you are looking for an element of the previous `<li>` with class "design", but there is none (your image in the previous `<li>` has class "photography")

Comment: omg i lold when you pointed that out :P 

sorry for the stupid question and thank you for the answer :)

i will mark it as an answer as soon as i can ...

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li .description").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).prev().find(".design").trigger('mouseout');
    });

    $("li .description").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).prev().find(".design").trigger('mouseover');
    });
});
```